# Swing with responsive UI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling

I have a Main Class, a UI class and an Interface handling callbacks from UI to main:

Main:

```
package clascomms;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author stef
 */
public class ClassComms implements Handler{

    private final ClassCommsUi ui;
    
    public ClassComms() {
        // private final ClassCommsUi ui;
        ui = new ClassCommsUi(this,"Click1","Click2");
}
    
    @Override
    public void btn1Clicked(){
        try {
            // this code should run if button 1 is clicked
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClassComms.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("bt1Clicked");
    }
    @Override
     public void btn2Clicked(){
    // this code should run if button 2 is clicked
         System.out.println("bt2Clicked");
    }
    
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ClassComms thisOne = new ClassComms();
    }
    
    
}
```

UI:

```
package clascomms;

/**
 *
 * @author stef
 */
public class ClassCommsUi extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Handler mainClass;
    public ClassCommsUi(Handler mainClass, String btn1, String btn2) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
        initComponents();
        jButton1.setText(btn1);
        jButton2.setText(btn2);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

   
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // If this action happens, method btn1Clicked() in main Class should be called 
    
      mainClass.btn1Clicked();
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // If this action happens, method btn2Clicked() in main Class should be called 
        mainClass.btn2Clicked();
    }    
   
    public void quit(){}

    
   

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And finally Interface :

```
package clascomms;

/**
 *
 * @author stef
 */
public interface Handler {
    public void btn1Clicked();
    public void btn2Clicked();
     
    
}
```

As you see, there is a 5 second Thread.sleep() in the main class...
When I click the button, it will stay pressed untill the sleep is over - the UI stays 100% unresponsive.
Is there a **simple** (NOOB here...) way to let the UI remain responsive?

Comment: Seems like you pasted `ClassComms` twice by mistake, instead of `ClassCommsUI`.

Comment: The freeze in the GUI is cause by the `Thread.sleep()` on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This is the thread that is responsible for the GUI updates, and you are blocking that. Use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for this kind of task.

Comment: @maloomeister : Thanks, you're right - i've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking EDT(Event Dispatch Thread). All Swing related code runs on EDT, that includes your `actionPerformed`. Try sleeping on a background thread.

```
@Override
public void btn1Clicked(){
   new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

      @Override
      protected void doInBackground() throws Exception {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClassComms.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
         System.out.println("bt1Clicked");
      }
   }().execute();
}
```

Comment: Well, works fine untill the ().execute(); part - i've got an error i can't get past... Netbeans tells me to create a method called execute. Some import i'm missing?

Comment: Please post the error. `SwingWorker` has a method name `execute()`. Since I wrote this off the top of my head, I could have done a typo, or you didn't implement it correctly.